# Reload class in Groovy

Tags: java, class, groovy

I have a custom ClassLoader extending `GroovyClassLoader` which compiles the source code to `.class` files on disk and then loads the resulting class:

```
class MyClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {

  File cache = new File( './cache' )
  Compiler compiler

  MyClassLoader() {
    CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration( targetDirectory:cache )
    compiler = new Compiler( cc )
    addClasspath cache.path
  }

  @Override
  Class findClass( name ) {
    try{
      parent.findClass name
    }catch( ClassNotFoundException e ){
      compiler.compile name, getBodySomehow()
      byte[] blob = loadFromFileSystem name
      Class c = defineClass name, blob, 0, blob.length
      setClassCacheEntry c
      c
    }
  }

  @Override
  void removeClassCacheEntry​(String name) {
    Class c = cache[ name ]
    super.removeClassCacheEntry​(name)
    GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass c
    deleteFiles name
  }
}

Class clazz = myClassLoader.loadClass 'some.pckg.SomeClass'
```

Now if I change the source code, call `myClassLoader.removeClassCacheEntry​(name)` and try `myClassLoader.loadClass()` again I'm getting:

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  com/my/MyClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name some/pckg/SomeClass

I read the greater half of the Internet and found a "solution" to initialize a class-loader for each class:

```
MyClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClassLoader()
Class clazz = myClassLoader.loadClass 'some.pckg.SomeClass'
```

This seems to be working but raises performance concerns of mine...

What is the proper way to reload classes? How can I reuse the same class-loader? What am I missing?

Comment: i think the problem that `removeClassCacheEntry​` removes classes loaded as groovy, and `findClass` uses java class loader to load `.class`

Comment: @daggett the `classCache​` is needed to avoid recompiling the same source code over and over again. Technically I can call `gcl.parseClass()` with the same source code as many times as I like, the problem remains though: the older classes are not removed explicitly from JVM

Comment: then don't use java native way to load `.class` files from cache (classpath, etc). you have to load them as it was groovy loaded then groovy lethod `removeClassCacheEntry​` should work

Comment: @daggett I'm pretty sure that `gcl.parseClass()` instantiates a new inner loader upon each run. If I run `println gcl.parseClass( body ).classLoader` several times it prints different hash codes

Comment: I tend to think now that my code is perfect, or in other words it's the best I can get out of the worst

Comment: Can you explain how such classes are used?

Comment: @GotoFinal the source code of those classes is persisted in a DB and then microservices can pull them and compile or deploy it locally, and then execute them

Comment: then using that separate class loaders is a pretty good and safe solution

Comment: @daggett you can put some answer down so the bounty doesn't just expire

Comment: @GotoFinal you can put some answer down so the bounty doesn't just expire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a trick that could be used

Originally, when you call

```
classLoader.defineClass(className, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length)
```

It calls java native method `defineClass1` that actually calls `loadClass` method.

So, possible to intercept this method and process it a bit different then original.

In the folder that contains cached class files I have the following groovy compiled to class: `A.class`

```
println "Hello World!"
```

`B.class` to check dependent class loading

```
class B extends A {
    def run(){
        super.run()
        println "Hello from ${this.getClass()}!"
    }
}
```

and `C.class` to check multi-level class loading

i used this [jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.5) to compile following class and run the class re-loading example

```
class C extends org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils {
    def rnd(){ nextInt() }
}
```

the following class + code loads and reloads the same class:

```
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.AccessController;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException;

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class CacheClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader{
    private File cacheDir = new File('/11/tmp/a__cache')

    private CacheClassLoader(){throw new RuntimeException("default constructor not allowed")}

    public CacheClassLoader(ClassLoader parent){
        super(parent)
    }
    public CacheClassLoader(Script parent){
        this(parent.getClass().getClassLoader())
    }

    @Override
    protected Class getClassCacheEntry(String name) {
        Class clazz = super.getClassCacheEntry(name)
        if( clazz ){
            println "getClassCacheEntry $name -> got from memory cache"
            return clazz
        }
        def cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, name.tr('.','/')+'.class')
        if( cacheFile.exists() ){
            println "getClassCacheEntry $name -> cache file exists, try to load it"
            //clazz = getPrivelegedLoader().defineClass(name, cacheFile.bytes)
            clazz = getPrivelegedLoader().defineClass(name, cacheFile.bytes)
            super.setClassCacheEntry(clazz)
        }
        return clazz
    }

    private PrivelegedLoader getPrivelegedLoader(){
        PrivelegedLoader loader = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<PrivelegedLoader>() {
            public PrivelegedLoader run() {
                return new PrivelegedLoader();
            }
        });
    }
    public class PrivelegedLoader extends CacheClassLoader {
        private final CacheClassLoader delegate

        public PrivelegedLoader(){ 
            super(CacheClassLoader.this)
            this.delegate = CacheClassLoader.this
        }

        public Class loadClass(String name, boolean lookupScriptFiles, boolean preferClassOverScript, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException, CompilationFailedException {
            Class c = findLoadedClass(name);
            if (c != null) return c;
            return delegate.loadClass(name, lookupScriptFiles, preferClassOverScript, resolve);
        }
    }
}

def c=null
//just to show intermediate class loaders could load some classes that will be used in CacheClassLoader
def cl_0 = new GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
cl_0.addClasspath('/11/tmp/a__cache/commons-lang3-3.5.jar')
//create cache class loader
def cl = new CacheClassLoader(cl_0)

println "---1---"
c = cl.loadClass('A')
c.newInstance().run()

println "---2---"
c = cl.loadClass('A')
c.newInstance().run()

println "---3---"
cl.removeClassCacheEntry('A')
c = cl.loadClass('A')
c.newInstance().run()

println "---4---"
c = cl.loadClass('B')
c.newInstance().run()

println "---5---"
cl.removeClassCacheEntry('A')
cl.removeClassCacheEntry('B')
c = cl.loadClass('B')
c.newInstance().run()

println "---6---"
c = cl.loadClass('C')
println c.newInstance().rnd()
```

result:

```
---1---
getClassCacheEntry A -> cache file exists, try to load it
Hello World!
---2---
getClassCacheEntry A -> got from memory cache
Hello World!
---3---
getClassCacheEntry A -> cache file exists, try to load it
Hello World!
---4---
getClassCacheEntry B -> cache file exists, try to load it
getClassCacheEntry A -> got from memory cache
Hello World!
Hello from class B!
---5---
getClassCacheEntry B -> cache file exists, try to load it
getClassCacheEntry A -> cache file exists, try to load it
Hello World!
Hello from class B!
---6---
getClassCacheEntry C -> cache file exists, try to load it
226399895
```

PS: not sure priviledged access required

Comment: What is this cacheDir and when something is saved to it? If I just copy that code, its not used at all

Comment: And what it will change? at the end there will be separate class loader for each class anyways

Comment: It's a directory where something stores compiled classes. could be this class that intercepts groovy parsing by overwriting `createCollector`. or parallel process that calls groovyc. in any case it was not a theme for this question :-) I could show how to do that by modifying response.

Comment: just before `defineClass` called in `GroovyClassLoader.ClassCollector.createClass` it's possible to store it into file cache. https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.java#L501

Comment: @daggett If the class extends another class, I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError` regarding the super class during loading, but the compilation works just fine. How can I fix it?

Comment: @injecteer, I've added two more test cases in code above - and it works fine.

Comment: @daggett Thank you! What if the "A" class is not located inside the cache dir? If it's a generic class or interface residing inside the deployable jar? How to tell CacheClassLoader to look for classes inside the parent app's classpath?

Comment: @injecteer, you have to specify parent class loader that knows required class. use the parameter of the constructor `new CacheClassLoader(SomeParentAppClass.class.getClassLoader())`.

Comment: that's what I was using when I got NoClassDefFoundError. I'll double check it

Comment: i've added another test )

Comment: your code works fine with 1 addition: in `loadClass()` I added `try{ delegate.parent.loadClass() }catch(e){ delegate.loadClass() }` to fix loading of classes like `groovy.lang.Closure`

Answer (score 1):

JVM does not allow to just unload some class, the only way to unload a class is to GC it. And class can be GC just like every other object -> all reachable references must be removed and GC run.
The tricky part is... class loader hold references to all classes. So the only way to unload a class is to get rid of both class and class loader.

You can find more information in language specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/jvms13.pdf 12.7 Unloading of Classes and Interfaces

> An implementation of the Java programming language may unload classes.
>   A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class
>   loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed in
>   §12.6. Classes and interfaces loaded by the bootstrap loader may not
>   be unloaded.

And class unloading does not need to be implemented at all in some JVM implementations:

> Class unloading is an optimization that helps reduce memory use.
>   [...] system chooses to implement an optimization such as class
>   unloading. [...] Consequently, whether a class or interface has been unloaded
>   or not should be transparent to a program.

There is also explanation why class loader can't be reachable to unload class, as class might contain static variables and blocks of code that would be reset and executed again if this same class would be later loaded again. It's quite long and already a bit off topic so I will not paste it here.

**So each your script should just use own class loader as that's the only way to actually not waste memory**, so class can be GC later. Just make sure that you don't use any libraries that might cache references to your class - like many serialization/ORM libraries might do this for data types, or some other reflection libraries.
Another solution would be to use different scripting language that does not create java classes and just execute some kind of AST structure.

There is also one more solution to this problem, but it is very tricky and it's not something you should use on production, it even requires you to provide special JVM arguments or JVM from JDK that contains all needed modules. As java supports instrumentation API that can allow you to change bytecode of class at runtime, but if class is already loaded you can only change bytecode of methods, you can't add/remove/edit method/field/class signatures. So it could be very bad idea to use it for such scripts, so I will stop here.