# (de)serialization of parsed Groovy scripts

Tags: java, groovy, scripting

We want to enable our customers to customize certain aspects of their requests processing, by letting them write *something* (currently looking at Groovy scripts), then have those scripts saved in a DB and applied when necessary, this way we won't have to maintain all those tiny aspects of processing details that might apply to certain customers only.

So, with Groovy, a naive implementation would go like this:

1. `GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(); // prepare execution engine - probably once per thread`
2. (retrieve script body from the DB, when necessary)
3. `Script script = shell.parse(scriptBody); // parse/compile execution unit`
4. `Binding binding = prepareBinding(..); script.setBinding(binding); // provide script instance with execution context`
5. `script.run(); doSomething(binding);`

When run one after the other, step 1 takes approx. 800 msec, step 3 takes almost 2000 msec, and step 5 takes about 150 msec. Absolute numbers will vary, but the relative numbers are quite stable. Assuming that step 1 is not going to be executed per-request, and step 5 number execution time is quite tolerable, I am very much concerned with step 3: parsing the Groovy script instance from the source code. I did some reading across the documentation and code, and some googling as well, but has not thus far discovered any solution, so here's the question:

Can we somehow pre-compile groovy code ONCE, then persist it in the DB and then re-hydrate whenever necessary, to obtain an executable `Script` instance (that we could also cache when necessary) ?

Or (as I am just thinking now) we could just compile Java code to bytecode and persist it in the Db?? Anyway, I am not so much concerned about particular language used for the scripts, but sub-second execution time is a must.. Thanks for any hints!

NB: I am aware that `GroovyShellEngine` will likely cache the compiled script; that still risks too long of a delay for first time execution, also risks memory overconsumption...

UPD1: based on excellent suggestion by @daggett, I've modified a solution to look as follows:

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
final Class<? extends MetaClass> theClass = shell.parse(scriptBody).getMetaClass().getTheClass();

Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(theClass, binding);
script.run();
```

this works all fine and well! Now, we need to de-couple metaclass creation and usage; for that, I've created a helper method:

```
    private Class dehydrateClass(Class theClass) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
        outputStream.writeObject(theClass);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
        final ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        return (Class) inputStream.readObject();
    }
```

which I've dested as follows:

```
    @Test
    void testDehydratedClass() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        RandomClass instance = (RandomClass) dehydrateClass(RandomClass.class).newInstance();
        assertThat(instance.getName()).isEqualTo("Test");
    }

    public static class RandomClass {
        private final String name;

        public RandomClass() {
            this("Test");
        }

        public RandomClass(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

which passes OK, which means that, in general, this approach is OK.

However, when I try to apply this `dehydrateClass` approach to `theClass`, returned by `compile` phase, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Script1

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:686)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1554)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
```

so, my impression is, that this de-serialization trick will not do any good, if the ClassLoader in question does not already have knowledge of what constitutes a `Script1`.. seems like the only way to make this kind of approach work is to save those pre-compiled classes somehow somewhere .. or may be learn to serialize them differently

Comment: Groovy shell engine is not caching anything. Classloader inside it - holds compiled classes. You could compile and store compiled version of each script in the db or in the file system. Compile on change is a good point to validate the script itself. Here is a question that is very close to yours IMHO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373661/reload-class-in-groovy/58592752#58592752

Comment: that brings up some good points, indeed. So question is now how to 'persist' parsed script in a way that could be later picked up by loadClass.. probably 'Script#metaclass' is what I'd need for that

Comment: @daggett I've expanded on the question; if you could have a second look?

Comment: i've already prepared an answer for you. and you extended your question )))

Comment: that's so cool! I'll look into it first thing in the morning!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can parse/compile scripts/classes during editing and store compiled version somewhere - in database, file system, memory, ...

here is a groovy code snippet to compile script/class to a bytecode and then define/load classes from the bytecode.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.BytecodeProcessor
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

//bytecode processor that could be used to store bytecode to cache(file,db,...)
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class BCP implements BytecodeProcessor{
    Map<String,byte[]> bytecodeMap = [:]
    byte[] processBytecode(String name, byte[] original){
        println "$name >> ${original.length}"
        bytecodeMap[name]=original //here we could store bytecode to a database or file system instead of memory map...
        return original
    }
}

def bcp = new BCP()
//------ COMPILE PHASE
def cc1 = new CompilerConfiguration()
cc1.setBytecodePostprocessor(bcp)
def gs1 = new GroovyShell(new GroovyClassLoader(), cc1)
//the next line will define 2 classes: MyConst and MyAdd (extends Script) named after the filename
gs1.parse("class MyConst{static int cnt=0} \n x+y+(++MyConst.cnt)", "MyAdd.groovy")

//------ RUN PHASE
//   let's create another classloader that has no information about classes MyAdd and MyConst 
def cl2 = new GroovyClassLoader()

//this try-catch just to test that MyAdd fails to load at this point 
// because unknown for 2-nd class loader
try {
    cl2.loadClass("MyAdd")
    assert 1==0: "this should not happen because previous line should throw exception"
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}

//now define previously compiled classes from the bytecode
//you can load bytecode from filesystem or from database
//for test purpose let's take them from map
bcp.bytecodeMap.each{String name, byte[] bytes->
    cl2.defineClass(name, bytes)
}

def myAdd = cl2.loadClass("MyAdd").newInstance()
assert myAdd instanceof groovy.lang.Script //it's a script

myAdd.setBinding([x: 1000, y: 2000] as Binding)
assert myAdd.run() == 3001 // +1 because we have x+y+(++MyConst.cnt)

myAdd.setBinding([x: 1100, y: 2200] as Binding)
assert myAdd.run() == 3302 

println "OK"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've wanted, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm compiling thousands of scripts like this so this has been very helpful.