# Is it possible to compile Groovy and then transfer the compiled code to another server?

Tags: groovy, jvm

Is it possible to compile a Groovy script on a server, transfer the bytecode to a different server and run it there?

This is Groovy v1, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Compile it w/ groovyc? (With all normal JVM caveats, e.g., you need all its dependencies etc.)

Comment: I don't understand. After compilation on Server A, how would I run it on server B? BTW, I use `GroovyShell`'s `parse` method to compile.

Comment: Same way you’d run any Java code. Are you asking how to get a file from one machine to another?

Comment: `groovyc abc.groovy` creates `abc.class` file which is a compiled version of `abc.groovy` - then just copy it to another server and run it as any java class.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm compiling it with [GroovyShell.parse](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#parse(groovy.lang.GroovyCodeSource)). Is there any way to serialize the resulting `Script` object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198381/deserialization-of-parsed-groovy-scripts/65203049#65203049

Comment: @daggett Almost, since I'm using Groovy v1, as I mentioned. The interface BytecodeProcessor doesn't exist in that version. I suppose I could patch it in, but that might be awkward. But anyway looks like a good direction.